# Type Mismatch: cannot convert from Object to ObjectName

Tags: java, class, object, type-conversion, type-mismatch

I have a Class named Filial.
On my Main class, i created a ArrayList of it:

`ArrayList<Filial> filiais = new ArrayList<Filial>();`

Still on my Main, i created a method:

```
    public static void atualizaFiliais(ArrayList filial){
        Filial thisFilial = filial.get(0); // <======Error
```

But i get this error when i try do this, thats say:

> 'Type mismatch cannot convert from Object to Filial'

Why cant i do this?

I also tried to set its attributes but also get error, for example:

**Filial.java**

```
public class Filial {
    String nome, endereco, contato, codigo;
```

**Main.java**

```
   public static void atualizaFiliais(ArrayList filial){
             String txta;
             txta = filial.get(0).nome //<====== Error
```

in that case it happens to appear the error on nome:

> 'nome cannot be resolved or is not a field'

Comment: You have to add the parameter type to the array list: `atualizaFiliais(ArrayList filial)` -> `atualizaFiliais(ArrayList<Filial> filial)`

Comment: What you have now is called a raw type: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it